# Passing object list to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, google-maps-markers, android-arrayadapter

In my code I am creating an area object by placing markers on map and taking its values from user then storing it in a list. Then I used parcelableArrayList to pass this list to another activity. What I want is that user presses displayArea button only then this activity is launched and list is displayed in AllAreas activty. But my app crashes whenever I click that button

Code for mapActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends    
 FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener,MapDropdown.DialogListener {

public static final String mapLongitude="longitude";
public static final String mapLatitude="latitude";
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Button displayareas;
Switch deleteareas;
private boolean del = false;
private int set = 0;
public ArrayList<Area> areas;


private GoogleMap newmap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
LatLng m;
float radius;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayareas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
    displayareas.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteareas = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    areas = new ArrayList<Area>();
    deleteareas.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                del = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleting enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                del = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleting disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    Log.d("Map","MapCreated");
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.display) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AllAreas.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", areas);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (newmap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        newmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (newmap != null) {
            setUpMap();
            Log.d("MAPS","Map working");


        }
        else Log.d("MAPS","not working");

    }
}


private void setUpMap() {

    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    newmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type
    newmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    newmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My location"));

    Log.d("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.d("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            if(del == false){
                m=marker.getPosition();

           MapDropdown dFragment = new MapDropdown();
            // Show DialogFragment
            dFragment.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");}
            else if(del == true){
                marker.remove();
            }
            return true;


        }

    };

    newmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);

    newmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);


            // Animating to the touched position
            newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker mmarker = newmap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            m = latLng;
            Log.d("ADDED LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
            Log.d("ADDED LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Block area updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog , String s, String n){
    Log.d("Button","positive");
    Log.d("Name",n);
    Log.d("Radius",s);

    Log.d("On press LATITUDE",String.valueOf(m.latitude));
    Log.d("On press LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(m.longitude));
    Area newarea = new Area(n,m.latitude,m.longitude,Float.valueOf(s));
    Log.d("object",newarea.getId());
    Log.d("object",newarea.getName());
    areas.add(newarea);
    areas.get(0);
    Log.d("areas",areas.get(0).getName());



}
@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog){
Log.d("Button","negative");

  }
 }
```

Part of mainActivity.java adding to list is

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog , String s,
 String    n){
    Log.d("Button","positive");
   //areas is list name
    //m is current marker
    Area newarea = new Area(n,m.latitude,m.longitude,Float.valueOf(s));

    areas.add(newarea);



}
```

And of passing list in mainactivity is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 //id of button that will launch Allareas activity
    if (v.getId() == R.id.display) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AllAreas.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", areas);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

for AllAreas class

```
public class AllAreas extends ActionBarActivity {
//initial  layout
private Area a;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.areas);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Area> arealist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
    if (arealist.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("area list lala", "is empty");


    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < arealist.size(); i++) {
            a = arealist.get(0);
            Log.d("area list lala", a.getName());
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you have a crash, you should post a complete stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it with wrong key.you used the key "data" for putting it into bundle and trying to get it by the key "mylist"

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", areas);
```

change the line

```
ArrayList<Area> arealist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
```

to

```
ArrayList<Area> arealist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("data");
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: This solved the problem. @sourabh Every time I restart the app. All list data is lost. How can I save list data?

Comment: If you want to save an object , there are three ways..
1. put it into shared preferences in the form of Json or string.
2. write it into plain text file and read later.
3. put it into database and fetch later.

Comment: if this solved your problem,then kindly make it the accepted answer.